# Change class depending on API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, openweathermap

I would like to change class to my div container depending on the response from the API. More specifically if the API return a temp over 0 degrees I want the background to be red, and if below I want it to be blue. (Will be images later but for now, colors.)

I would like to check what `celsius={this.state.celsius}`.

UPDATE WITH ALL CODE

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Search from './components/Search';
import Form from './components/Form';

const API_KEY = '*********************'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      city: undefined,
      celsius: undefined,
      wind: undefined,
      feelsLike: undefined
    };
  }
     
evenDeagree(temp){
  let cell = Math.floor(temp)
  return cell;
}   

getWeather = async (e) => {   
  try {
  e.preventDefault();
   "city."
  const city= e.target.elements.city.value;
 datan.
  if(city){    

    const api_call = await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${API_KEY}`
    );
    reponse
    const response = await api_call.json();
    console.log(response)

    this.setState({
      city: "City: " + `${response.name}`,
      celsius: "Current Degree: " + this.evenDeagree(response.main.temp) + "°C",
      wind: "Wind m/s: " + this.evenDeagree(response.wind.speed),
      feelsLike: "Känns som: " + this.evenDeagree(response.main.feels_like) + "°C"

      });
  }   
} 

catch(error) {
  document.getElementById("errMessage").innerHTML =  "City not found, please try again";
  
}

}

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="mainContainer">
      <Form loadweather={this.getWeather}/> 

      <div className={this.state.celsius > 0 ? "red" : "blue"}>
      <Search 
          city={this.state.city} 
          celsius={this.state.celsius}
          wind={this.state.wind}
          feelsLike={this.state.feelsLike}
        />
        </div>

    </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you want class to be `background-color-red` or `background-color-blue` or `background-color-standard` based on condition?

Comment: You can use a ternary operator here to determine which class to assign, like so
```className={this.state.celsius > 0 ? "red" : "blue"}```

Comment: Yes, i though i could apply 2 different background-images on two different classes and just toggle class depending on what the API-reponse is, in this case response.main.temp >= 0. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, with help of useState, you can set the state with default class and update the class with network request completion.

Or you can use css modulse and add an class array and join another class if your condition is not met, etc.

Here is a example below to help you understand how to pass classname dynamically.

Code Sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-gagarin-ugy7d?file=/src/styles.css:0-162

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () =>
{
  const [className, setClassName] = useState("App");

  useEffect(() => 
  {
    //Fake Api Cal
    setTimeout(() => 
    {
      setClassName("App-New");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


/*styles.css*/
.App 
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: green
}


.App-New 
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: red
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a clear reply. However im not using any useEffect yet im only 3 days in React so far. I bet when doing  this or that like what i want here a simpler solution is this condition rendering i guess? :)

Comment: If you post more code on how you are making network requst and storing those values, that could make us help you more better with conditional styling.

Comment: I updated the thread :) Cheers.

Comment: @Niqqo , So did you get the answer for your question or still having trouble ?